# Why jQuery UI dialog is 5 pixels to high

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, terminal, jquery-ui-dialog

I have strange issue with jQuery UI dialog when I put terminal inside, the title bar is to high. It's fixed when I set

```
.ui-draggable .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Using CSS inspector but when I set that in CSS file or in html the title is 5 pixels to low and when I remove the margin the position is right.

Why is this happening?

I'm calling `dialog` and `terminal` ([dterm wrapper](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/js/dterm.js)) on the same selector [Demo](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#biwascheme).

Answer (score 0):

If that code fixes the problem, then just add that to your jquery.ui.css file.

Comment: If I set the margin in CSS then when I run the page the title is 5 pixel too low, so when I remove it it's right.